# java.util.zip.DataFormatException: incorrect data check

Tags: jsf, firefox, richfaces, servlet-filters

I am getting the below mentioned error while loading the JSF page. The page gets loaded successfully and the desired operation on the page is also done but this error comes.

The JSF page contains tab panels and if I try to include some items from available items to included items, the error comes. Following is the XHTML of the lists.

```
<a4j:outputPanel id="selectItems">
    <div id="div_selectItems" class="scroll_container">
        <s:div styleClass="dialogueAttribute">
            <rich:listShuttle sourceValue="#{itemReportEditor.itemsList}"
                              targetValue="#{itemReportEntry.itemReportData}"
                              var="items"
                              listsHeight="28em"
                              sourceListWidth="45em"
                              targetListWidth="45em"
                              sourceCaptionLabel="Available Items"
                              targetCaptionLabel="Included Items"
                              removeAllControlLabel="Remove all"
                              removeControlLabel="Remove"
                              copyControlLabel="Add"
                              copyAllControlLabel="Add all"
                              fastOrderControlsVisible="true"
                              orderControlsVisible="true"
                              converter="#{itemReportEditor.itemReportDataModelConverter}">
                <rich:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText title="Performance item name"
                                      value="Name"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{items['itemName']}"></h:outputText>
                </rich:column>

                <rich:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText title="Performance Item Protocol"
                                      value="Protocol"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{items['protocol']}"></h:outputText>
                </rich:column>

                <a4j:support event="onlistchanged"
                             action="#{itemReportEntry.updateItemsList()}"
                             reRender="la"
                             oncomplete="resizeScrollBox2();"
                             status="workingStatus"
                             eventsQueue="ajaxQueue"/>
            </rich:listShuttle>
        </s:div>
    </div>
</a4j:outputPanel>
```

I am trying to add some items using list shuttle from left hand side to right hand side and I am getting the following exception (only in FireFox browser, did not observe this issue in Google Chrome) in logs (able to apply all the changes properly, just getting the following exception). My FireFox version is 35.0.1

```
2015-04-06 15:42:34,272 ERROR [http-0.0.0.0-8080-8] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost].[/client].[Faces Servlet]
Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception

javax.faces.FacesException: Error decode resource data
    at org.ajax4jsf.resource.ResourceBuilderImpl.decrypt(ResourceBuilderImpl.java:627)
    at org.ajax4jsf.resource.ResourceBuilderImpl.getResourceDataForKey(ResourceBuilderImpl.java:369)
    at org.ajax4jsf.resource.InternetResourceService.serviceResource(InternetResourceService.java:156)
    at org.ajax4jsf.resource.InternetResourceService.serviceResource(InternetResourceService.java:141)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:488)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.Ajax4jsfFilter.doFilter(Ajax4jsfFilter.java:56)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:60)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:190)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:433)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:598)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.util.zip.DataFormatException: incorrect data check
    at java.util.zip.Inflater.inflateBytes(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.Inflater.inflate(Inflater.java:238)
    at java.util.zip.Inflater.inflate(Inflater.java:256)
    at org.ajax4jsf.resource.ResourceBuilderImpl.decrypt(ResourceBuilderImpl.java:621)
    ... 30 more
```

Googling I found "The problem seems to be that characters like '!' are converted by FireFox to '%21'. The following filter will convert the %21 back to '!' so resource can be found in the server"

In my case, I am just getting the exception in logs but all the sources are successfully loaded

In order to eliminate the exception, I added the filter

```
package juno.sa.server;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLDecoder;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper;

public class RichFacesFirefox11Filter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        chain.doFilter(new HttpServletRequestWrapper((HttpServletRequest) request) {
            @Override
            public String getRequestURI() {
                try {
                    return URLDecoder.decode(super.getRequestURI(), "UTF-8");
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {

                    throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot decode request URI.", e);
                }
            }
        }, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        // do nothing
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        // do nothing
    }
}
```

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>RichFacesFirefox11Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>juno.sa.server.RichFacesFirefox11Filter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>RichFacesFirefox11Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.seam</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: So if your resources are being loaded and the filter prevents the exception what is the problem?

Comment: resource is loaded, but i am getting the exception in logs, i donot want to have that exception

Answer (score 0):

Even i am receiving such exception.
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: incorrect data check
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:147)

But in my case root cause would the stream which i a m trying to read is compressed using flate encoder, hence the stream that is trying to uncompress is InflaterInputStream.

What happens in my case is the data present in the last byte is not eof parameter its an actual data, the eof parameter is present in the stream somewhere before the last byte. So when the stream ream last byte of block data, it is unable to find the eof hence throws incorrect data check.

Maybe verify it at your end... it could be same issue at your end too.